# Service Cloud Console - openSubtab() not working

Tags: service-cloud-console, knowledge, tab, subtab-apps

I followed the example provided on this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_opensubtab.htm).

I am trying to open a knowledge article on a new sub-tab in the Service Console, the sub-tab does open but it does not display any content. It keeps 'processing' but nothing appears.

I also tried to replace the article's link to the one generated by the service console but I got the same results.

```
<apex:page standardController="Case">

<A HREF="https://cs80.salesforce.com/articles/en_US/Procedure/No-Icon/p" onClick="testOpenSubtab();return false">
    Click here to open a new subtab</A> 

<apex:includeScript value="/support/console/22.0/integration.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function testOpenSubtab() {
        //First find the ID of the primary tab to put the new subtab in
        sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(openSubtab);
    }

    var openSubtab = function openSubtab(result) {
        //Now that we have the primary tab ID, we can open a new subtab in it
        var primaryTabId = result.id;
        sforce.console.openSubtab(primaryTabId , 'http://www.salesforce.com', false, 
            'salesforce', null, openSuccess, 'salesforceSubtab');
    };

    var openSuccess = function openSuccess(result) {
        //Report whether we succeeded in opening the subtab
        if (result.success == true) {
            alert('subtab successfully opened');
        } else {
            alert('subtab cannot be opened');
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Did you add salesforce.com in whitelisted domains from your console app settings?

Comment: @tugce Yes I did...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the basic HTML and JavaScript behind this.

```
<A HREF="https://cs80.salesforce.com/articles/en_US/Procedure/No-Icon/p" onClick="testOpenSubtab();return false">
Click here to open a new subtab</A>
```

This is not meant to **OPEN** whatever link you have in the `href`. This is just a link that trips the function `testOpenSubtab()`then returns `false`, which means it is performing the onClick then **not** navigating to the `href` location, so it doesn't matter what is in that attribute.

The link it is actually opening is the second argument of `openSubtab()`, which in the example is "http://www.salesforce.com".

So this would work for your example:

```
sforce.console.openSubtab(primaryTabId , 'https://cs80.salesforce.com/articles/en_US/Procedure/No-Icon/p', false, 
        'salesforce', null, openSuccess, 'salesforceSubtab');
```

Comment: you are right! this is a bit confusing to put onclick function within an a tag! anyway, thanks a lot!